# Linux cpu usages high but clock speed is low

Tags: linux, performance, cpu, cpu-usage

I am running a game server (ark survival if it matters) on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 and when the number of users connected increases the CPU usages also increases, which is as expected.  But the clock speed is quite low.  It's i3-6100 and the clock speed ranges from 740mhz to 3700mhz.

But when this application is pushing the cpu usage towards 90% or more the clock speed is bellow 2000.  I know the game server in use is predominately single threaded, but I would expect the cpu to push towards it's max clock speed when the usages is high.  It does for some other software I have (python access mysql will and generating svg images files) it pushes past 3000 and toward peaks of 3700.

Is there something causing it to run slow that I don't understand?

Comment: is it lagging?  If not, then there is no issue.

Comment: It's not yet, but I suspect it will with another 5 or 6 players, and I that would bring the total online players to about 18.  That is not many.  I chose the i3-6100 for it's single threaded performance.